# iOS: KVO + Animation = No Animation?

Tags: ios, animation, key-value-observing

I am animating a view (moving its frame outside the screen) in a block like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, .0f, CGRectGetHeight(view.frame));
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // view is removed here
}];
```

This animation works wonderfully and smooth when triggered by a button press. After that, the view is removed and deallocated.

Now, if I put this into a KVO observer (value change triggered by UIGestureRecognizer):

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    // perform animation from above
}
```

then the view is simply removed after 0.3 seconds, but not animated downwards. I'm sure that all this is operating on the main thread.

Any ideas why the animation is not played?

**SOLUTION:**

The method in which the animation is performed was called multiple times, animating the view so fast downwards that it appeared as if it disappeared instantly. This must not happen, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle difference between `UIGestureRecognizer`'s target-action mechanism and the one of `UIControl` (`UIButton`): `UIControl` delivers the action immediately, upon detection of the touch event while `UIGestureRecognizer` schedules the action for the next pass through the run loop.

While this does not explain the missing animation it might still help to understand what's going on. Generally UIView animations do work when triggered from a gesture recognizer's action.

Comment: thanks! your answer pointed me in the right direction (knowing that it must be my own code's fault) - turns out the method was called multiple times.